# Is there a natural way to indicate directional motion in a still image?

Tags: illustration, effects, critique

I have made the following render of a DNA molecule being pulled through a hole in a membrane using Blender. Since this process can go in either direction, I need a way to indicate whether the DNA is moving upward or downward. So far nothing I have tried looks at all natural. Is there a natural way to indicate direction of motion in a still image such as this without adding virtual elements like arrows to the image?

[image]

Other critiques are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to color the segments like so:

[image]

This way the viewer has some visual reference to focus on. You can then add some blur or visual motion lines that would help accentuate the "motion".

Or you can also mess with the perspective of the final viewing angle to show depth or height depending on what your final look is for. You can even use blurring to create depth of field.

Here are some examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will play with some motion blur effects and see if I can come up with something that looks decent. Color coding the segments is a neat idea that I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 0):

You must fake. Have a setup which would be more improbable in macroscopic sizes, if the direction of the motion is assumed wrong.

Motion blur shows that motion exists.

One chain pile diminishes and in the other end another chain pile grows. Let the output from the diminishing pile be below the pile and the input to the growing pile be on the top of the pile. Otherwise it will seem a little more improbable even in case that some invisible hand lifted the moving part of the chain upwards.

Avoid apparent magical defeating the gravity, if possible. Let the motion be horizontal.